# Predicting the outcome on the test data

Tags: fitting

I have an issue with predicting the outcome variable from the test data based on a fitted model on the training data.

Here is the code:

```
sample = Sort[RandomSample[Range[nrow], Round[nrow * 0.6]]];
train = values[[sample]];
test = Delete[values, Partition[sample, 1]]; test // Length

logitAll = LogitModelFit[
   train, {x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8, x9, x10, x11}, {x1, x2, x3,
     x4, x5, x6, x7, x8, x9, x10, x11}, 
   NominalVariables -> {x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x9, x10, x11}];

logitAll["BestFit"]

1/(1 + E^(2.96427 - 5.04423*10^-6 x8 - 
 0.168057 DiscreteIndicator[x1, 
   "[10000,60000]", {"[10000,60000]", "(110000,160000]", 
   "(160000,210000]", "(210000,260000]", "(260000,360000]", 
   "(360000,1000000]",...)
```

There are lot of independent variables and the code is too long, so I cut the rest of the code.

I know that I can predict the outcome variable on my training data using the following code:

```
logitAll["PredictedResponse"]
```

But how to predict my dependent variable from my test data?

The first row of my data looks like this:

```
test[[1]]

{"[10000,60000]", "university", "[0,500]", "[0,500]", "[0,500]", 
"[0,500]", "(500,1500]", 0, "no consumption", "paid in full", "paid
in full", 1}
```

The last variable is the dependent variable.

I tried the following:

```
logitAll /. test
```

and

```
logitAll /. Transpose[Transpose[test][[1 ;; 11]]]
```

But it does not work. Since this works when there are no nominal variables in the model, I suppose it has to do something with nominal variables, but do not know how to solve this problem.

What should I do?
Thank you.

Comment: What is the definition of `values` in `train = values[[sample]];`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because one can make single predictions in the following manner

```
logitAll["[10000,60000]", "university", "[0,500]", "[0,500]", "[0,500]", 
  "[0,500]", "(500,1500]", 0, "no consumption", "paid in full", "paid in full", 1]
```

This should also work:

```
logitAll[# /. List -> Sequence] & /@ test[[All, Range[1,11]]]
```

Comment: Alternatively `logitAll @@@ test[[All, Range[1,11]]]`

Comment: @Coolwater Thanks!  That's much cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work:

```
vars = {x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8, x9, x10, x11};
logitAll["BestFit"] /. Thread /@ ReleaseHold[Thread[Hold[vars] -> Drop[test, 0, -1]]]
```